# Suggestions on vitamin c supplements

Tags: exercise, workout, supplements, vitamins

One of my friend is taking a gym training in any institute and he suggested me to take a **limcy medicine** which contain **vitamin c after workout** and its a very cheap tablets which anybody can afford.

**Limcy Tablet details**:http://www.catalog.md/drugs/limcee.html

So i just wanted to ask you guys that is it good to take such **vitamin c supplements after workout?**

Comment: What's gym training? More importantly, ***did he tell you why you should take the pills?***

Comment: Gym trainer training and he just told me that you should take dis before and after your workout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have any reason what so ever to assume you have a vitamin c deficiency (also known as scurvy) ? If not, don't waste your money, even if they're cheap. Supplement companies make loads of money on peoples ignorance and morally speaking, these companies should be starved until they go bankrupt.

It's incredibly easy to get all the vitamin c you need, if you eat fruit or vegetables, even in low amounts, you'll get all you need.

Comment: +1. Unless you can demonstrate a need for a supplement, don't start taking anything.

Comment: @EricKaufman:You are absolutely right about that.but as we are doing body building so we need lots of vitamins so i am asking you guys for that